# how do I explode an array that came in from an html form in coldfusion?

Tags: php, html, coldfusion

I am brand new to ColdFusion (as of today in fact). I don't know what version the server is using. I have read through some of http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Part_4_CF_DevGuide_1.html to try to get up to speed.

My big question at the moment is: what is the ColdFusion equivalent for this bit of PHP?

```
$numatt = $HTTP_POST_VARS['numatt'];
$att=explode(",",$numatt);
$attcount = count($att);
```

Here's the entire PHP script for context:

```
<?php
$nument = $HTTP_POST_VARS['nument']; # this is one number. My debug example is 2.
$numatt = $HTTP_POST_VARS['numatt']; # this is an indefinite number of numbers separated by commas. My debug example is 3,5.
$numval = $HTTP_POST_VARS['numval']; # this is one number. My debug example is 6.
echo 'number of entities is: $nument<br><br>';
$att=explode(",",$numatt);
$attcount = count($att);
echo 'the attributes are $numatt, which can be broken down to $att[1] and $att[2].<br><br>';
echo 'there are $numval values for each attribute.<br><br>';
for ($i = 1; $i = $nument; $i++) {
    echo 'this is round $i of the loop. It has $att[$i] attributes.<br><br>';
    for ($j = 1; $j = $att[$i]; $j++) {
        echo 'this is for attribute $j of entity $i.<br><br>';
        for ($k = 1; $k = $numval; $k++) {
            echo 'here is loop $k for $numval values.<br>';
        } #end $k
    } #end $j
} #end $i
?>
```

Basically I'll need to translate that from PHP into ColdFusion, but think I can figure out how to set up the loops if I spend enough time in the manuals. (Or I'll come back with more questions...) Pointers to better manuals or getting-started references would also be welcomed - I just found the one linked above via Google.

Comment: You'll love this page: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html

Comment: *just found the one linked above via Google* The adobe docs are good place to get started. Most of the function names are pretty self-explanatory. The [functions by category](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Functions+by+category) is also useful if you do not know the function name, but have an idea what it should do.

Comment: Side note, you can get the version number by logging into the CF Admin -or- by dumping the server variable: `<cfdump var="#server.coldfusion#">`

Comment: I suggest doing a tutorial so you can learn some basic stuff before attempting to do real work.

Comment: This is a guess, but $HTTP_POST_VARS looks like it might be the collection of form fields.  If that's true, you will have a list called form.fieldnames with which you can use list functions.

Comment: If you are new to CF, I highly suggest you to take look into http://www.learncfinaweek.com/ site. It will bring you up to the speed in no time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ColdFusion, you can easily convert a string into an array by using the `listToArray()` function. All form variables are bundled up for you in the `form` scope. All url variables are bundled up for you in the `url` scope.

```
<cfoutput>

    <!--- reference variables submitted through a form --->
    <p>name sent through form: #form.firstName#</p>

    <!--- reference variable in url --->
    <p>name in url: #url.firstName#</p>

    <!--- output a list of all fields submitted in a form --->
    <p>all form field names: #form.fieldNames#</p>

    <!--- quickly dump form and url data (for debugging purposes) --->
    <cfdump var="#form#">
    <cfdump var="#url#">

    <!--- output all form field data --->
    <cfloop collection="#form#" item="key">
      Form field name: #key#, form field value: #form[key]#
    </cfloop>

    <!--- converting strings into arrays, default delimiter is comma --->
    <cfset arr1 = listToArray("my,list,is,cool", ",")>

    <cfset arr2 = listToArray("my other list", " ")>

    <cfset arr3 = listToArray("yet:another:list", ":")>

    <!--- how many items in arr1? --->
    #arrayLen(arr1)#

    <!--- loop over arr3 --->
    <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(arr3)#" index="i">
      #arr3[i]#
    </cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```

CFML makes most everything easy. Bear in mind, CFML also offers a script syntax if you prefer not to use tags.

Comment: +1. Also most scopes are structures, so you can use associative array notation too ie `URL["firstName"]` or `FORM["firstName"]`. For more information: [About CFScript](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/About+CFScript)